# How do I make cross-sales on Woocommerce with a checkbox such as this (picture)

Tags: woocommerce

[image]

I want to make my website similar to this, where you can just click a checkbox and it adds the product to cart, and to the price counter as well.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, the plugin "UpSell for WooCommerce" is litterally this feature.